# Tests coverity and reusability problem

Tags: unit-testing

I am not very good at writing unit tests so I have a dilemma.
I have a `binary_search_tree` and I am writing tests for `insert` and `contains` methods:

```
struct BinarySearchTree {};

TEST(BinarySearchTree, Insert) {
    BinarySearchTree t;
    t.insert(5);
    EXPECT_TRUE(t.contains(5));
}

TEST(BinarySearchTree, Contains) {
    BinarySearchTree t;
    t.insert(5);
    EXPECT_FALSE(t.contains(2);
    EXPECT_TRUE(t.contains(5);
}
```

As you can see both of them are related each other and these test cases may be totally equal because:

1. We test insertion by inserting element and checking does the tree contain it.
2. We test existense of element by inserting it and checking does the tree contain it.

So I have 2 options:

1. Don't write tests for contains because it will be tested in { insertion, deletion, replacement, etc } tests.
2. Write almost same content in all of these tests.

What is better?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How should I test the functionality of a function that uses other functions in it?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/225323/how-should-i-test-the-functionality-of-a-function-that-uses-other-functions-in-i)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unit tests test a code unit, which may be larger than a method. It is usually not possible to test setter–getter and constructor–getter pairs separately, and that is OK. You'll naturally have test cases like “contains inserted elements” and “doesn't contain elements that weren't inserted”. In such cases, I focus my tests on that method which modifies the structure. Here, I'd probably use a single test case for contains–insert.

```
TEST(BinarySearchTree, ContainsInsertedElements) {
    BinarySearchTree t;
    EXPECT_FALSE(t.contains(5)); // precondition

    t.insert(5); // act

    EXPECT_TRUE(t.contains(5)); // assert
}
```

(and another case that inserting the same element again also works, and a high-level non-unit test case that I can insert multiple numbers which should produce an expected tree structure.)

For `contains`, I might switch to more white-boxy tests. In particular, insert and contains will probably have a common find operation that could be tested more carefully, and we can then assume that contains is likely correct as well.

Essentially duplicating a test just because the test body uses two methods does not seem like a good idea. Tests are code, and guidelines such as “don't repeat yourself” still apply (within reason). Also, duplicate tests don't add value: if one fails the other does too. It is better to focus on more general contracts of the unit under test, rather than narrowly focussing on each method no matter how useless it might be in isolation.

Comment: thanks much for the response but I have now 2 conflicting answers. Mostly I like and prefer yours but **DavidArno**'s answer has some good thoughts too. I am confused about what is better..

Comment: @VictorPolevoy: That is a strong indicator that the question is leaning towards the [Primary Opinion-based](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6491/) territory. You could just wait and see which opinion gets the more votes.

Comment: @VictorPolevoy, If you prefer this answer, then accept it. Both answers are opinions developed through experience and neither is wrong (though obviously mine is more right ;)). So pick the one that fits how you want to work. Just apply it consistently!

Comment: @DavidArno I just want you guys argue each other to define the truth but okay if you not gonna do that. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Both answers have some degree of opinion and are formed by our respective experiences, though I feel @DavidArno is closer to the mainstream opinion. We both consider fundamental concepts and goals of tests, but prioritize different objectives: efficiently bringing a code unit under test coverage in my case, discoverable tests for David. I personally have never seen real tests that can also serve as documentation, and therefore don't value discoverability very much. However, that might actually be rather important in your case, and provide a good argument for writing separate tests.

Answer (score 4):

Your test cases, if done well, serve two purposes:

1. They check that no existing functionality has broken when making changes to the code in the future;
2. They document how the code is to be used and how it behaves.

If you just had one check,

```
TEST(BinarySearchTree, Insert) {
    BinarySearchTree t;
    t.insert(5);
    EXPECT_FALSE(t.contains(2));
    EXPECT_TRUE(t.contains(5));
}
```

Then it fails to achieve the second benefit: `EXPECT_FALSE(t.contains(2));` is buried inside an `Insert` check and so isn't obvious to the user.

So whilst it is slightly more code to write the two tests, it's much clearer what the tests are doing if you do. That's a huge advantage when compared to just saving a few lines of code.